# OnChange event on Input File using JQuery doesnt work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi every one i have this piece of code:

```
        $("input#fileBrowse").click();
        $('#fileBrowse').change(function() {
            if($('#fileBrowse').val() != "")
            {
                //AJAX call to send the file
            } 
            else
            {
                return;
            }

        });
```

*#fileBrowse* is the id for the input file element, i trigger his event from code.

When someone insert rightly the file path, this code works properly. But if i press the close button in the input file dialog the code doesn't enter in the ELSE statement and send anyway the ajax call with an empty file name. Where's my problem?

```
<button class="nuovoButton" style="vertical-align:middle" onclick="displayDopdown();">
            <span> Nuovo </span>
            <div class="dropdown-content-nuovo" id="dropdown-content-nuovo">
                <a style="border-bottom:none;" id="newFile" onclick="openFileOption();"> <img src="upload.png" class="a-image"> Carica File </a>
                <input type="file" id="fileBrowse" style="display:none" >
                <a onclick="createDirectory();"> <img src="create-new-folder.png" class="a-image"> Crea Cartella</a>
            </div>
        </button>
```

Here's the markup

Comment: can you show your markup also

Comment: i have edited it

Comment: well, thats because "change" event does not get triggered when "Cancel"/"Close" button is pressed, as nothing changes.

Comment: @SudhirBastakoti but if the event doesn't fire at all, it doesn't explain why the ajax call is still fired. Although I fail to see how that could happen, I can't reproduce OP's problem.

Comment: @Interseba5 this HTML is bizarre, all this stuff nested inside a button. What do the displayDopdown() and openFileOption() and createDirectory() functions do? Seems like when you click the outer button, those inner functions might be called as well, but it's hard to tell what you're really clicking on due to wrapping it all up in a button. Is there a typo in your sample?

Comment: The displayDropdown() function dysplay the <a> wich are normally hidden because the button has a dropdown content. The openFileOption() function are the function where i have the problem, and the createDirectory() function is another ajax call that i use to create directory in a server

Comment: @SudhirBastakoti i recive two times the response from the AJAX call so i think that in the on change function it pass

Comment: @Interseba5 with minimal example i was not able to reproduce the issue you are are having. Could you create a sample in jsfiddle.net with the exact issue you are having..?

Comment: "The openFileOption() is where I have a problem". Is that the sample you've posted, or not? It isn't clear whether it's the same code, or whether that's all of the code in the function. As Sudhir mentioned, a JSFiddle that reproduces your problem would be nice (it doesn't have to include the ajax itself, just an alert showing where the ajax call would be is sufficient). Make an MCVE - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve